# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: python

В двумерном массиве (матрице) найти строку, сумма элементов которой является максимальной среди всех строк матрицы.

```
  s = s + a[j][i]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Не понимаю как исправить данную ошибку

Код:

```py
a = [[10, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 150, 1],
     [0, 110, 70, 0],
     [0, 0, 100, 0]]

max = 0
raw = 0
for j in a:
    s = 0
    for i in j:
        s = s + a[j][i]
    if s > max:
        max = s
        raw = j
print()
print(raw+1)
```

Comment: j и i это не индексы в данном случае, это значения массивов, переделайте на for j in range(len(a)) и for i in range(len(a[i]))

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что ты с помощью цикла берешь элемент списка.

```
a = [[10, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 150, 1],
     [0, 110, 70, 0],
     [0, 0, 100, 0]]

max = 0
raw = 0
for j in range(len(a)):
    s = 0
    for i in range(len(a[j])):
        s = s+ a[j][i]
    if s > max:
        max = s
        raw = j

print()
print(raw+1)
```